# Schengen visa for Au pairs

Tags: germany, france

I from Kazakhstan and I worked as an Au pair in France for 1 year in 2015-16 then I came back home and tried to get at the university in France but financially it wasn’t possible and I decided to come back again as an Au pair but my visa was refused, it was August 2018. This year I want to go to Germany as an Au pair but I have doubts that they might decline it too because I already have one visa denial. What are your thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What was the reason for the refusal?

Comment: For one year, you will need a national (D) visa rather and not a Schengen (C) visa. For those, ask on Expatriates Stack Exchange.

Comment: Because I already participated in this programm in 2015 and you can be an Au pair only once. I knew that but my friend did 2 years in a row like a few years ago and I just wanted to risk and it didn’t work out

Comment: After, last November 2018 I had Italian Schengen (C) and I guess even on tourist visa my French visa denial affected because I had to inform the consulate when I’m back home, they gave me only 7 days. So that’s why I’m worried that Germany will not give me a national visa (D)

Comment: I will move this to Expatriates, if there is an option for you the people there are more likely to know about it.